# writing a gui application that acts a cash register in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qpushbutton, qtoolbar, qtoolbutton

Please help me answer the following question: Write a gui that acts as a cash register.  In other words, a client brings a basket of items, their bar-codes are scanned, and their total is calculated.
The main window should have a menu bar with two menus: "Sale" and "Item".  The Sale menu should have the following options: "New", "Cancel", "Finalise" and "Exit". The Item menu should have the following options: "Add" and "Remove". The main window should also have a toolbar (at the bottom of the window) with a toolbar button for each of these options.

When the program starts, the "Cancel", "Finalise", "Add" and "Remove" options should be displayed (on the menus and the toolbar).

I am using Qt.  I am supposed to code the gui manually. I am not supposed to use Qt Designer to create the user interface.  I have read the relevant material but I just do not know how to start tackling this question.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not a site for you to get answers to your homework. You need to show us that you have made some sort of attempt to answer the question yourself, before presenting us with your workings (code samples, errors, etc.) and asking a question. This is why you have been severely downvoted.

Comment: Wasn't looking for the answer but direction@DuncanKinner.

Comment: How can I add toolbar buttons to my program.  Here is what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound too bad, I know you can do it.

What you will want to start out with is a main function looking something like this...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QApplication app (argc, argv);

   QPushButton saleButton ("Sale");

   saleButton.show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

That will give you a window with a Sale button on it! Now all you need to do is customize it to your liking, and add more buttons. The biggest challenge you will face is most likely the signals/slots which will be connected to the buttons so that you be able to actually make them do things.

Take a look at this page for some more guidance. https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners

Comment: Thanks.  You have given me the much needed direction. I'm working on the program

Comment: This is somewhat helpful. So is [this](http://i.imgur.com/uXEFceJ.jpg).

Comment: My program is almost fine but I need some help. I want to add toolbar buttons at the bottom of the Window. Here is my program: